# Can NHibernate's QueryOver syntax select MAX() of an SqlFunction?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, nhibernate

I have registered an SQL function in my dialect subclass

```
RegisterFunction("addseconds", new SQLFunctionTemplate(NHibernateUtil.Date, "dateadd(second, ?1, ?2)"));
```

which can be used in queries like so

```
var q = _session.QueryOver<Event>()
    .Select(
        Projections.SqlFunction(
            "addseconds",
            NHibernateUtil.Date,
            Projections.Property<Event>(x => x.DurationInSeconds),
            Projections.Property<Event>(x => x.StartTime)));
```

producing the SQL

```
SELECT dateadd(second,
               this_.DurationInSeconds,
               this_.StartTime) as y0_
FROM   [Event] this_
```

but what I'm really after is

```
SELECT MAX(dateadd(second,
               this_.DurationInSeconds,
               this_.StartTime)) as y0_
FROM   [Event] this_
```

unfortunately I can't seem to get SelectMax to take a Projections.SqlFunction. Can it be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to update the NHUtil to be DateTime:

```
RegisterFunction("addseconds", new SQLFunctionTemplate(NHibernateUtil.DateTime, "dateadd(second, ?1, ?2)"));
```

Otherwise you will only be dealing with the Date portion.

Your query is fine, you just need to wrap it in a Projections.Max() like so:

```
var q = _session.QueryOver<Event>()
                .Select(Projections.Max(Projections.SqlFunction(
                        "addseconds",
                        NHibernateUtil.DateTime,
                        Projections.Property<Event>(y => y.DurationInSeconds),
                        Projections.Property<Event>(y => y.StartTime))))
                .SingleOrDefault<DateTime>();
```

I just quickly wrote a test, (different naming than above) and it produced the query:

```
SELECT max(dateadd(second,
                   this_.DurationInSeconds,
                   this_.SomeDate)) as y0_
FROM   Employee this_
```